# Multilingual URL changes to weird characters after launching app via URL scheme

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, url-scheme, cjk

I am to using url scheme provided by iOS to launch my app from external source like from website. For example I have created a HTML file which has code as below. The query string contains some Japanese characters.

```
<html>
<a href="myapp://?appid=12345&destination=奈良県奈良市雑司町406-1">Visit Todaiji</a>
</html>
```

My app opens successfully by this url scheme when I open this html file in safari simulator and tap on link "Visit Todaiji".

The problem is when I receive this url in open url delegate

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool 
{
     return true      
}
```

The url gets converted to as below

```
myapp://?appid=12345&destination =å¥ˆè‰¯çœŒå¥ˆè‰¯å¸‚é%E2%80%BA‘å%C2%8F¸ç”º406-1
```

I have tried many types of encodings (like, UTF-8, ASCII, nonLossyASCII) to convert the string back to Japanese but nothing worked. If the html file is opened in Mac Safari and the link is clicked the same behaviour can be seen in the safari address bar as well. Is it possible to get the string back in Japanese from the url.

Answer (score 1):

URI should not have raw Japanese (and many other international languages') characters. Your parameter value should be percent-encoded.

That garbled parameter might be a result that the raw Japanese text is decoded as a percent-encoded string.

What happens if you use this for the href?

`myapp://?appid=12345&destination=%e5%a5%88%e8%89%af%e7%9c%8c%e5%a5%88%e8%89%af%e5%b8%82%e9%9b%91%e5%8f%b8%e7%94%ba406%2d1`

Comment: could you please confirm if the string in destination parameter could be changed back to Japanese text.

Comment: You may convert it on some online url-decode site, such like https://www.urldecoder.org/ . It is the same one you wrote in your question.